# How to compare and convert const reference and const_iterator

Tags: c++

Here is a simplified version of what I have to deal with. I got a struct that holds a number, one that holds a vector of numbers, and one that holds a ref to a number.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Number{
  int a;
  Number(int b): a(b){}
};

struct NumberCollection{
    vector<Number>::const_iterator begin(){return numberVec.begin();}
    vector<Number>::const_iterator end(){return numberVec.end();}
    NumberCollection(){numberVec.emplace_back(5);  numberVec.emplace_back(7); numberVec.emplace_back(11);}
    private:
    vector<Number> numberVec;
};

struct NumberRef{
  Number const & myNumber;  
    NumberRef(Number const & input):myNumber(input){}
};

int main()
{

  NumberCollection collection;
  vector<Number>::const_iterator vec_it = collection.begin() +1;
}
```

First, I want to make a `NumberRef` using `vec_it`. Second, I want to compare `Number` structs by their address, since `NumberCollection` is going to hold all the Numbers that will ever exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, first, to make a `NumberRef` you actually just have to deference the iterator.

```
NumberCollection collection;
  vector<Number>::const_iterator vec_it = collection.begin() +1;
  NumberRef numberRef(*vec_it);
```

Second, to compare the address of the two, consider this:

```
cout << to_string(&(numberRef.myNumber) == &(*vec_it)) << endl; // prints out "1"
```

The iterator is like a pointer to a `Number`, so you dereference it to get a `Number`, and use `&` to get the address of the `Number`.

Remember, this comparison only works if you're comparing the exact same `Number`  structs, and not for `Number` structs that have equivalent data.

```
Number a(7);
  cout << to_string(&(numberRef.myNumber) == &a) << endl; //prints out "0"
```

Which can be good or bad depending on what you need.

Comment: It isn't necessary to `std::to_string` an integer before passing it to `std::cout`. `std::cout` can print integers on its own.

Comment: That's true (bool in this case),  and another set of parentheses would have done the trick. Old habits die hard, I guess.